# php class html-dom dosen't return all the html

Tags: php, html

I want to retrieve  all  links from www.gifgif.ir

the all of  I need have /product and they are 360.but I only get 37.

My code is:

```js
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: saleh
 * Date: 10/16/17
 * Time: 9:58 PM
 */
set_time_limit(-1);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
// example of how to use basic selector to retrieve HTML contents
include('/home/saleh/Downloads/simple_html_dom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');

// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.gifgif.ir/');
$c="";
// find all image with full tag
foreach($html->find('a') as $e){
    if (isset($e->attr['href'])) {
        if (strstr($e->attr['href'], "/product")) {
            if ($c == $e->attr['href']) {
            } else {
                echo $e->attr['href'] . "\n";
                $c= $e->attr['href'];
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

But it returns only 10 links. What should I do to get all the links to return?

```js
http://www.gifgif.ir/product/pId-2HnAXuEJBRdsM4
http://www.gifgif.ir/product/pId-TeYhzl2oPwnIgr
http://www.gifgif.ir/product/pId-KoYUDejZa7Jc9m
http://www.gifgif.ir/product/pId-r1H0kayBexIcXF
http://www.gifgif.ir/product/pId-FaLdA5P4WqDyXi
http://www.gifgif.ir/product/pId-lYXV65Fw0NzB3e
http://www.gifgif.ir/product/pId-Gc1uxSp6tHFmhi
http://www.gifgif.ir/product/pId-Qe3TZltc2WEpvj
http://www.gifgif.ir/product/pId-ybZ2kPLewHojsd
http://www.gifgif.ir/product/pId-yJS8czqOMT7vjB
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of a link that you aren't seeing that you think you should be? You are currently filtering to only show links with "/product" in them.

Comment: Please look at the source of that page. It only contains 10 unique links that contains `/product` so I would say that your script is doing exactly what's expected.

Comment: http://www.gifgif.ir/product/index/pId-dCWLN4g69eMjq1/%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%86%D9%85-%DB%8C%D9%87-%D8%A8%D8%AF%D9%86%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%B4%D9%86%DA%AF%D9%88%D9%84-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%A7%DA%86-%D8%AE%DB%8C%D9%84%DB%8C-%D8%AC%D8%AF%DB%8C-%DA%AF%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%AA%DB%8C%D8%A7

Comment: There is no link on the URL you're pulling with a "product/index" path

Comment: for example I can't get this link : http://www.gifgif.ir/product/index/pId-dCWLN4g69eMjq1/%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%86%D9%85-%DB%8C%D9%87-%D8%A8%D8%AF%D9%86%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%B4%D9%86%DA%AF%D9%88%D9%84-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%A7%DA%86-%D8%AE%DB%8C%D9%84%DB%8C-%D8%AC%D8%AF%DB%8C-%DA%AF%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%AA%DB%8C%D8%A7

Comment: What makes you think that you _should_ be getting that link. It's not on the page. You should clarify what you're really trying to accomplish. Your words say "i want to get all .gif links", but your code contradicts this by filtering to only links containing "/product". You're also saying you want a link that isn't even on the page. So what are you really trying to do here?

Comment: I want to get all .gif links and all of them links have /product.and when I erase the  if (strstr($e->attr['href'], "/product")) { I get 30 links which isn't usable for me.

Comment: There _aren't any_ `.gif` files linked on that page (neither in `img` tags nor in `a` tags). Unless you can provide sample input HTML and show what parts of it you want to match and what parts you don't, you're not going to get an answer.

Comment: look I want to get all the links.the links count is about 300 but I only get 30.the links which I get is in the box.the other links dosen't show.what should i do???

Answer (score 0):

The content on the page is loaded dynamically - the first served page only contains a subset of the actual HTML. If you watch the Network tab under the developer tools in your browser of choice, you'll see that it loads contents (the `getList` call) as you're scrolling.

You'll have to work around that by making requests to the actual endpoint that loads content, and not just read the initial content served by the page. Since I'm guessing the site content creator don't want their API to be exposed in public, I'm not going to write code that actually does this, but you should be able to create a loop that makes calls to `getList`, parses the HTML and extracts the relevant data.

Comment: tnx for you're answer can you explain more about the loop??I am searching a long time.please help me